# NameError: name 'the_given_file' is not defined while being in the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I try to import a file Python which is in the same folder with the jupyter notebook I'm calling it. It worked well until some point when I shut down the kernel and relaunched it :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-28aefea88e42> in <module>
      1 import imp
      2 from stocker import Stocker
----> 3 imp.reload(stocker)

NameError: name 'stocker' is not defined
```

I also tried with `importlib` :

```
import importlib
from stocker import Stocker
importlib.reload(stocker)
```

But it didn't worked neither.

Thus I thought it was a Path problem so I added it with `sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance')`

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python36.zip
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions
C:\Users\antoi\.ipython
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxi5uysfy
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvwwnclc1
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0bf8ff56cd18> in <module>
      6 import importlib
      7 from stocker import Stocker
----> 8 importlib.reload(stocker)
      9 
     10 import imp

NameError: name 'stocker' is not defined
```

But it doesn't work ...

I also tried from the anaconda prompt and it is the same error. My OS is Windows10.

#### Update

I tried to get rid of `imp.reload()`. Now I import the file `stocker.py` with `from stocker import Stocker`. Yet, how can I load the former library then ?

Comment: `stocker` was a variable that you had already declared in your notebook. Then you restarted the kernel, so it wiped it. Maybe you define it further down in the code? Try running that cell first

Comment: In order for `stocker` to refer to the module, so that it makes any sense to call `importlib.reload(stocker)`, you would have to do `import stocker`.  `from X import Y` does not give you any name by which to refer to the module itself.